# Ajax response handling and assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello i have some problem with ajax response handling

i have a global function **call**() that makes ajax calls and just returns json response:

```
function call(request_url,params) {
    $.post(request_url,params,function(response) {
        return response;
    },'json');
}
```

After that i have an object GetServices that uses global function **call()**

```
    var GetServices = {
      service_url:"http://xxx.com/req.php",

      getCurrency:function() {
            var resp = call(this.service_url,{act:'getCurrency'});
            return resp;
      }
    }
```

I want **GetServices.getCurrency()** to return the ajax response but it returns undefined. Javascript assigns value **undefined** to it and after that finishes ajax call.

Please help me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will not work because the call is still executing while the `resp` variable is being set, therefore `resp` will always be `null`.

The alternative is to pass a delegate function to the `call` function to run on `$.post` success, or change the `$.post` to be a synchronous `$.ajax` call.

Answer (score 0):

Its an asynchronous call...
Therefore it will make a call and resume its processing. You will get the value somewhere after making the call. It depends on various factors. For eg, your server's response time.

The easiest way is to call the target function (the function to which you want to pass this ajax value to) from your success handler of `$.post()`

For eg

```
function call(request_url,params) {
    $.post(request_url,params,function(response) {
        yourTargetFunction(response); // instead of returning the value from this
    },'json');
}
```